# How to get spring boot Initializr project working in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I unzip a maven zip from the initializr site and open in Intellij, a green arrow appears in the gutter to the left of the main method of the application java file, so I can start running the project.

What exactly causes that arrow to appear automatically?

I ask because I cloned one of my projects and that green arrow does not appear like it does from the source of the clone, so I need to determine what configuration setting is wrong or missing.  That file does not have a C next to it until I mark the src directory as a sources root, and after that, the annotations are in red since I guess the classpath isn't configured, and I want to know how these settings got automatically picked up by a vanilla file extracted from the initializr site

Comment: Intellij supports several modes of project types.
1. Maven (pom.xml)
2. Gradle (build.gradle)
For the above two, after Intellij opens the project directory, it can automatically configure the relevant JDK and Classpath ( xxxx.jar ), Source Code directory, compiled output directory, etc. according to pom.xml and build.gradle

3. IntelliJ project
You need to manually set the JDK environment, Source Code directory, compiled output directory, etc., as well as the required Classpath (xxxx.jar),

Comment: Finally, you need to configure Configuration, whether to use Current File or specify a specific Java file as the Java program to be executed

Answer (score 0):

Check in Project Settings (in IDEA) if JDK is set.
It is the first reason why project can't be built (when JDK is not set)

Then IDEA automatically launches project building, but if it doesn't you should do it manually.
Depends on building manager you use: maven or gradle you need to run the appropriate command in IDEA CLI or found the tab (often on left side of GUI) and launch procedure by clicking at "refresh" button.

After project is built icons of packages, classes, resources will be changed and IDEA provide you some extra editor lightnings and marks and oppotunity to start or debug Spring project (in your case).

Shortly, main reason why you can't start your cloned project is that you don't clone the rules for building with it (I guess), so IDEA doesn't see what to do and does nothing and you don't get dependensies that are nessesary for successful start of project.

To deeply understand try:

1. check JDK (as I mentioned above)
2. make sure that build file is present in root (pom.xml or gradle.build)
3. manually launch the build
   After that you should get desirable result.

For details of work you can read information for your manager (maven, gradle)